# How to replace body class in Angular [ BEST WAY ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

in my index.html I have my `<header>` then `<body>` with some subelements and `<footer>` elements.

Rest of the code is in template for each page like templates/home.html, templates/login.html

For one of this page I need to replace:

```
<body class="page-homepage" ng-app="historyApp" id="body">
```

to

```
<body class="page-subpage" ng-app="historyApp">
```

Is there some nice way how to do it?

I find some ways with jquery like (take it as example):

```
var el = document.querySelector('#body');
el.classList.remove('page-homepage');
el.classList.add('page-subpage');
```

but I believe that many of you already had to deal with this is kind of problem.
Can someone suggest me how to do this in angular?

Comment: Have you looked at `ng-class`?

Comment: Just a note: while you already have `document.body` no reason for search it by id

Comment: "Best way" is create directive and service for this. Set home/sub through a service and watch for this inside directive with service too. Use of `$rootScope` is simple, but can't to be `best way`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to do this is to add a variable to your $rootScope

```
$rootScope.isSub = false;
```

And use ngClass directive on your body element :

```
<body ng-class="{'page-subpage':isSub,'page-homepage':!isSub}" ng-app="historyApp">
```

And for each controller specify the $rootScope.isSub value.